# Nested NIntegrate problem

Tags: numerical-integration

So I've been trying to evaluate the following integral in Mathematica 8.0 Student version:

```
opsnum[a_, ω_] := (c^5*(3*10^25))/ℏ*
      NIntegrate[ρ[y, ω]/
        Hubble[y, ω]*(1/Hubble[z, ω])^3, {y, 
        a, ∞}, {z, a, y}]
```

with

```
    Hubble[z_, ω_] := 
 H0 Sqrt[ΩM (1 + z)^3 + Ωγ (1 + 
      z)^4 + ΩΛ ((1 + 
       z)^(3*(1 + ω)))]

χ[a_, ω_] := 
 NIntegrate[c/Hubble[z, ω], {z, a, ∞}]
ρ[a_, ω_] := (3*Matter[a, ω])/(
 4 π*(χ[a, ω])^3)
```

My problem is that this refuses to converge, and gives me an `NIntegrate::inumr` error, due to the nested integral nature of the function. Furthermore, I cannot think of another definition for the function as it relies on the cube of an integral which has limits different from the limits of the total integrand, of which it is a part.

Anyone got any ideas? I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: You've got undefined terms, so `NIntegrate` can't evaluate; that's what `inumr` means. A simpler example is `NIntegrate[a, {t, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: sorry, I meant to include that the variables are defined in my table, which is where the function's values are displayed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You get that error because some or all of your variables don't have a numerical value. I don't know what you mean by saying that they are defined in your table, but apparently they weren't defined at the time of execution of the `NIntegrate`. Please provide more details about what you were doing.

Answer (score 2):

The NIntegrates should be combined into one call:

```
NIntegrate[\[Rho][ y, \[Omega]]*(c/Hubble[z, \[Omega]])^3, {y, a, \[Infinity]}, {z, a, y}]
```

Otherwise, the inner integral remains in symbolic form when the outer integral is run.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for that. I tried that as well and I still get an inumr error. Is that I've tried reversing the order of integration as well in desperation, but to no avail.

Comment: Make sure that both your rho function and Hubble function are defined in the following way: `functionname[x_?NumericQ] := function goes here`

Comment: Hiya, all my numbers have been defined in a previous cell, and I have a seperate cell that specifies my loops and/or iterators as part of the ParallelTable command.

Comment: Add `?NumericQ` after each of the arguments in the declaration of Hubble and rho, as I described in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi Guillochon, I tried that too but now it gives me a different error - slwcon. I increased the working precision but it still does this. Any advice on how to circumvent this? Thanks for the tips by the way!

Comment: Try setting `MaxRecursion->15` in the NIntegrate call. Also, considering you are probably using real units for Friedmann's equation, you might want to scale all the units down to numbers ~unity. Anyhow, I feel like I'm doing your homework here, so good luck!